# How can we do groupby on multiple values in rdd?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For ex : rdd looks like `Array(["vijay",21,"pune","male"],["ajay",31,"mymbai","male"],["alia",21,"delhi","female"])`

I want to do groupBy on `city` and `gender`(not using dataframe)

`rdd.groupBy(x=>x(2),x(3)).collect` throws error but `rdd.groupBy(x=>x(2)).collect` works fine

Can any suggest how to groupBy multiple elements in rdd ?

Comment: `rdd.groupBy(x=>(x(2),x(3))).collect` check this

Answer (score 0):

Check the example below -

```
val list = List(("a","b","c"),("x","y","z"),("p","b","c"))
val temp = sc.parallelize(list)
temp.groupBy(x => x._2+x._3).collect
```

Output is

```
Array[(String, Iterable[(String, String, String)])] = Array((yz,CompactBuffer((x,y,z))), (bc,CompactBuffer((a,b,c), (p,b,c))))
```

Note that groupBy() takes in an element in RDD (in this case tuple of 3 values) and returns back a key with which records could be grouped by.

Here is the groupBy Definition for your reference

```
def groupBy[K](f: ((String, String, String)) => K,p: org.apache.spark.Partitioner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering, I found one more solution to this :

Val newrdd = rdd.map{case(name,age,city,gender) => ((city,gender),name,age)}.groupbykey()